# How to import Tor Browser profile

Tags: firefox, fingerprinting

To make a Tor Browser from Firefox ESR there are many settings should be changed for the about:config, so can I have a way to change these values in a shorter time or can I directly use Tor Browser in the TBB folder, so that what setting should I do?

```
1 # Default Preferences
2 # Tor Browser Bundle
3 # Do not edit this file.
4
5 // Disable browser auto updaters and associated homepage notifications
6 pref("app.update.auto", false);
7 pref("app.update.enabled", false);
8 pref("browser.search.update", false);
9 pref("browser.rights.3.shown", true);
10 pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
11 pref("startup.homepage_welcome_url", "");
12 pref("startup.homepage_override_url", "");
13
14 // Disk activity: Disable Browsing History Storage
15 pref("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);
16 pref("browser.cache.disk.enable", false);
17 pref("browser.cache.offline.enable", false);
18 pref("dom.indexedDB.enabled", false);
19 pref("permissions.memory_only", true);
20 pref("network.cookie.lifetimePolicy", 2);
21 pref("browser.download.manager.retention", 1);
22
23 // Disk activity: TBB Directory Isolation
24 pref("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false);
25 pref("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", false);
26 pref("browser.download.manager.addToRecentDocs", false);
27
28 // Misc privacy: Disk
29 pref("signon.rememberSignons", false);
30 pref("browser.formfill.enable", false);
31 pref("signon.autofillForms", false);
32 pref("browser.sessionstore.privacy_level", 2);
33
34 // Misc privacy: Remote
35 pref("browser.send_pings", false);
36 pref("geo.enabled", false);
37 pref("geo.wifi.uri", "");
38 pref("browser.search.suggest.enabled", false);
39 pref("browser.safebrowsing.enabled", false);
40 pref("browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled", false);
41 pref("browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone", false); // prevents AV remote reporting of downloads
42 pref("extensions.ui.lastCategory", "addons://list/extension");
43
44 // Fingerprinting
45 pref("webgl.min_capability_mode", true);
46 pref("webgl.disable-extensions", true);
47 pref("dom.battery.enabled", false); // fingerprinting due to differing OS implementations
48 pref("dom.network.enabled",false); // fingerprinting due to differing OS implementations
49 pref("browser.display.max_font_attempts",10);
50 pref("browser.display.max_font_count",10);
51 pref("gfx.downloadable_fonts.fallback_delay", -1);
52 pref("general.appname.override", "Netscape");
53 pref("general.appversion.override", "5.0 (Windows)");
54 pref("general.useragent.locale", "SHPONKA");
55 pref("general.oscpu.override", "Windows NT 6.1");
56 pref("general.platform.override", "Win32");
57 pref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
58 pref("general.productSub.override", "20100101");
59 pref("general.buildID.override", "20100101");
60 pref("browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID", "20100101");
61 pref("general.useragent.vendor", "");
62 pref("general.useragent.vendorSub", "");
63 pref("dom.enable_performance", false);
64 pref("plugin.expose_full_path", false);
65 pref("browser.zoom.siteSpecific", false);
66 // pref("intl.accept_languages", "en-us, en"); // Set by Torbutton
67 // pref("intl.accept_charsets", "iso-8859-1,*,utf-8"); // Set by Torbutton
68 // pref("intl.charsetmenu.browser.cache", "UTF-8"); // Set by Torbutton
69
70 // Third party stuff
71 pref("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 1);
72 pref("security.enable_tls_session_tickets", false);
73 pref("network.http.spdy.enabled", false); // Stores state and may have keepalive issues (both fixable)
74 pref("network.http.spdy.enabled.v2", false); // Seems redundant, but just in case
75 pref("network.http.spdy.enabled.v3", false); // Seems redundant, but just in case
76
77 // Proxy and proxy security
78 pref("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
79 pref("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
80 pref("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", true);
81 pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
82 pref("network.security.ports.banned", "9050,9051,9150,9151");
83 pref("network.dns.disablePrefetch", true);
84 pref("network.protocol-handler.external-default", false);
85 pref("network.protocol-handler.external.mailto", false);
86 pref("network.protocol-handler.external.news", false);
87 pref("network.protocol-handler.external.nntp", false);
88 pref("network.protocol-handler.external.snews", false);
89 pref("network.protocol-handler.warn-external.mailto", true);
90 pref("network.protocol-handler.warn-external.news", true);
91 pref("network.protocol-handler.warn-external.nntp", true);
92 pref("network.protocol-handler.warn-external.snews", true);
93 pref("plugins.click_to_play", true);
94 pref("plugin.state.flash", 1);
95 pref("plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin", true);
96
97 // Network and performance
98 pref("network.http.pipelining", true);
99 pref("network.http.pipelining.aggressive", true);
100 pref("network.http.pipelining.maxrequests", 12);
101 pref("network.http.pipelining.ssl", true);
102 pref("network.http.proxy.pipelining", true);
103 pref("security.ssl.enable_false_start", true);
104 pref("network.http.keep-alive.timeout", 20);
105 pref("network.http.connection-retry-timeout", 0);
106 pref("network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy", 256);
107 pref("network.http.pipelining.reschedule-timeout", 15000);
108 pref("network.http.pipelining.read-timeout", 60000);
109 // Hacked pref: Now means "Attempt to pipeline at least this many requests together"
110 pref("network.http.pipelining.max-optimistic-requests", 3);
111
112 // Extension support
113 pref("extensions.autoDisableScopes", 0);
114 pref("extensions.bootstrappedAddons", "{}");
115 pref("extensions.checkCompatibility.4.*", false);
116 pref("extensions.databaseSchema", 3);
117 pref("extensions.enabledAddons", "https-everywhere%40eff.org:3.1.4,%7B73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232%7D:2.6.6.1,torbutton%40torproject.org:1.5.2,ubufox%40ubuntu.com:2.6,tor-launcher%40torproject.org:0.1.1pre-alpha,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:17.0.5");
118 pref("extensions.enabledItems", "langpack-en-US@firefox.mozilla.org:,{73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232}:1.9.9.57,{e0204bd5-9d31-402b-a99d-a6aa8ffebdca}:1.2.4,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:3.5.8");
119 pref("extensions.enabledScopes", 1);
120 pref("extensions.pendingOperations", false);
121 pref("xpinstall.whitelist.add", "");
122 pref("xpinstall.whitelist.add.36", "");
123
124 // Omnibox settings
125 pref("keyword.URL", "https://startpage.com/do/search?q=");
126
127 // Hacks/workarounds: Direct2D seems to crash w/ lots of video cards w/ MinGW?
128 // If only the first one is set to true then the Tor Network Settings are blank
129 // on some Windows machines.
130 pref("gfx.direct2d.disabled", true);
131 pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand your question? Do you want to use a plain firefox ESR and change settings? Why not use Tor Browser in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

There are [numerous patches](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/log/?h=tor-browser-31.6.0esr-4.5-1) applies to FireFox ESR to make Tor Browser, so you cannot make one just with configuration options and [extensions](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/what-are-the-changes-made-to-firefox-in-the-tbb/6591#6591).