# How to initialize chrome with tor proxy from command line?

Tags: web-proxy, chrome

I tried method 1 from here: http://justplainobvious.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/how-to-configure-google-chrome-for-tor.html but it doesn't work. When I check my ip in http://whatismyip.com it remains the same.

Comment: The site https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings has a documentation for the option `--proxy-server`. However I tested several versions, but none of them worked. Maybe there is a bug in Chrom(e|ium) or in the documentation.

Comment: A quick google suggests people have had more success with port 9050 for socks5, in place of 8118. (I couldn't give you a reason for this though... )

Answer (score 2):

[My answer assumes you're trying to use Chrome as a replacement for the TBB, to the same anonymous ends.]

To cut a long story short: don't use Chrome.

Even if you get it "working", your privacy won't be as protected as it is when using the Tor Browser Bundle and the modified version of Firefox contained therein.

For more details on why not to use Chrome, see the [Tor FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser) (which itself links to and article on the Tor Blog describing [the problems with Chrome](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting)).

For more information about the changes that have gone into Firefox - and therefore what isn't present in Chrome - this thread would be a good place to start:
[What are the changes made to Firefox in the TBB?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/what-are-the-changes-made-to-firefox-in-the-tbb/6591#6591)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for an equivalent to TBB. I need Torified Chrome for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have the answer you want but have two options for you:

1. You may try configuring your whole computer to connect to Internet and route all connection via a Tor-ed device (e.g, another Tails PC). As it has been done in this paper: ([A Tor-Based Anonymous Communication Approach to Secure Smart Home Appliances](http://goo.gl/41LR7a)). However, it seems like you need a lot of engineering effort to set up such a system.
2. You may try buying this [Safeplug](http://goo.gl/P2BO3N). It acts as your Tor-Proxy just within some easy configuration steps.

Best Regards.

Comment: Careful with the Safeplug recommendation! See https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/annee/security-audit-of-safeplug-tor-in-a-box/ -- most of these little Tor hardware gadgets are snake oil.