# Security of other browsers + Tor vs. Tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, chrome, proxy

I'm a bit confused about why using Tor with regular Chrome or FF is considered insecure.

Let's say I use it with Chrome. I install the "Expert Bundle", then the proxy-switchy Chrome extension and set up a Tor profile (Host: 127.0.0.1:9050, Socks 4). And disable the Flash player from `chrome://plugins` because Flash ignores the proxy.

Can it be said that at this point Chrome is just as secure as the Tor Browser, assuming I always use incognito mode? If not, can anyone please explain how is the browsing any different compared to that on a Tor Browser (what else makes it insecure besides Flash and cookies)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Chrome through Tor on OS X?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-can-i-use-chrome-through-tor-on-os-x)

Comment: This thread may also be of use: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6589/what-are-the-changes-made-to-firefox-in-the-tbb/6591#6591

Comment: (And this: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting)

Comment: I think @RichardHorrocks covered this. Read about the Tor Browser build process and you can see all of the (substantial) differences between the two. A good example is how in Chrome, any web page can identify your _internal_ and/or public IP via WebRTC - something disabled in TBB. There are just so many security benefits of TBB so you have to read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be anonymous.

Tor Browser is made to have the same user agent, fingerprint, and settings for all users (if they don't install add-ons), so sites can't tell Tor Browser users from each other.

Chrome (and other browsers) is not an anonymous browser and [doesn't have fingerprinting defenses](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting), so if you simply set Chrome to use as a proxy, your fingerprint will be unique and trackable across all sites you visit.

There are also many possible leaks that can and will leak your IP address.

Chrome also contains telemetry from Google that will leak metadata about your browsing.

**Tor Browser is the only browser designed for anonymity and recommended for use with Tor.**